# Conditionally mark a checkbox as checked in Meteor using Blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm not entirely sure what's wrong here, or how I'm supposed to approach it differently - but googling just brings up references to 'isChecked' - something I'm not using.

I just want to flag a checkbox as checked if the associated field value is present:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="services.bananaExports" {{ #if currentUser.profile.services.bananaExports }} checked {{ /if }} />
```

But I'm getting:

> Reactive HTML attributes must either have a constant name
>      or consist of a single {{helper}} providing a dictionary of names and
>      values.  A template tag of type BLOCKOPEN is not allowed here.

Honestly I'm not sure what that's trying to tell me, I'm new to meteor/blaze but it's a pretty basic if clause? Can I not issue an if statement here? If not how would I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I can think of is to define a helper like this one:

```
Template.registerHelper('isTruthy', function(varName) {
  return !!varName;
});
```

Then you can do things like this:

```
{{#each foodList}}
  {{foodName}} <input type="checkbox" checked={{isTruthy eaten}}>
{{/each}}
```

Of course, in your case:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="services.bananaExports" checked={{isTruthy currentUser.profile.services.bananaExports}}>
```

Comment: Thanks @ffxsam - I did in fact end up with something similar, within the helper: `return (value == 'on' ? 'checked' : false);`.

Comment: That's very specific though, and it may be better to have a more general helper. The `isTruthy` helper can be used in many different scenarios, e.g. `<button disabled={{isTruthy Session.get('loading')}}>`.

Comment: @NathanHornby PS: editing my code to use a global helper so you can use across all templates

Comment: Sorry, disregard the above, you can't actually reference `Session` in Blaze. I'll edit that comment when the time limit expires for me..

Comment: @ffxsam The time limit is for everyone. You can't change a comment after five minutes.

Comment: Oh, bummer. Anyway, the `isTruthy` helper is handy for any variables you can actually pass into it. For checking `Session` var truthiness in Blaze, you'd need a separate global helper.

Comment: I was just looking at how to turn it into a global helper - so thanks! (and good point about making it more general, the less redundancy and the more reusability the better I say!)