# How to deal with checkboxes in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

Following from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055096/conditionally-mark-a-checkbox-as-checked-in-meteor-using-blaze) it appears I have to go around the houses with Meteor just to flag a checkbox as checked - but I've been Googling for an hour now and I can't find any examples of how to actually do it.

**I've created the base of a helper:**

```
Template.Settings.helpers({
  isChecked: function () {
    var id = this.id;
    console.log(id);
  }
});
```

**And here's the HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="imaname" id="imanid" {{isChecked}} />
```

However I'm clearly misunderstanding the context of `this` as literally whatever I try returns undefined (`this.target` etc. all nada). No docs I can find elaborate on how to actually create the `isChecked` helper that I'm supposed to use, so I'm now lost and frustrated.

Where do I go from here?

**Edit:** OK so I have it working, however I'd still like to know what the context of `this` is (maybe a duh moment, I guess the context is the helper itself… how do I access the element that triggers the helper?) - so I can make it a little more dynamic:

```
Template.Settings.helpers({
  isChecked: function (value) {
    return (value == 'on' ? 'checked' : false);
  }
});
```

Along with:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={{ isChecked currentUser.profile.services.bananaExports }} />
```

Comment: What is `id`, how are you setting it, on what?

Comment: I'm trying to get the id of the checkbox that's triggering the helper. (although I actually want the name, this was just what someone else was using with success, so I thought I'd start there, but no idea what the context of `this` is)

Comment: Ah, I see! I thought it was from the template data. Is this `id`/`name` hard-coded, or does it come from some data source such as a collection?

Comment: it comes from the checkbox in the HTML :) My original assumption was that the context `this` was the element that triggered the helper - but now I've thought more on it that doesn't really make sense as it;s not being passed in - this must just be the helper itself. So how do I get the context of the element that triggers the helper?

Comment: I've edited the question with an update @Kyll - couple of duh moments there. But I'm assuming that there's a way to access the element context, similar to `event.target.text.value` in events? I may have misunderstood one of the examples I'd seen - maybe helpers don't know what element called them?

Comment: Maybe you could check [`Template.currentData()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata).

Answer (score 0):

> I'd still like to know what the context of this is

In a Blaze template helper `this` refers to the data context where the helper was called, which is the data context of the template unless you've set the context to be something else. To learn about data contexts see [Discover Meteor's Guide](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/) on the topic.

> how do I access the element that triggers the helper

Blaze doesn't have any way of telling you where in the DOM a helper was called, it only has access to the data context and any arguments you pass to the helper.

If you really have to access the DOM node you need to use [`Template.instance().find('some query')`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_find) or [`Template.instance().$('some query')`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_$) for a JQuery object.

An alternative way of marking a checkbox as checked is to define it like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="imaname" id="imanid" checked={{isChecked}} />
```

And then setting `isChecked` to true or false in your helper.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, here's my approach, instead of using helper, you better use blaze template event handler and jquery like below:

```
Template.Setting.event({
'click input'(event){
if($('#imanid').is(":checked") == true){
   return true;
}else{
   return false;
}
}
});
```

hope this helps